# How can arrange the string according to numbers provided in it

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have given a string **"my1kiran4name2is3"** and my expected output is **"my name is kiran"**

Explanation1

```
my - 1
kiran - 4
name - 2
is - 3
```

I have to arrange the words based on the numbers.
the string only contains numbers from 1 to 9.

So my output is **"my name is kiran"**

been trying to solve this problem from past two days but not finding any way just started learning java, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: by sorting it. create a composite object containing two values: key (the int) and value (the String). implement Comparator based on the key, sort your array, and print the values of the elements

Comment: alternatively you could first split the string and then put the substrings into corresponding index of an array then add them back into a string

Comment: can you please explain in code

Comment: Since you're just a beginner I assume you're not familiar with regex so try the following: 1) iterate through the characters of the string and check if they are a number (1-9). 2) If you've found a number get the word it belongs to by taking the substring from directly after the last number or index 0 if there was no last number yet. 3) put both the word and the number into a separate object and put that object into a list or array. 4) sort the list as Stultuske suggested. 5) reconstruct the string by iterating over the list and concatenating the words - separating them with spaces.

Comment: @NeelChavan we are not going to provide you with custom made code. SO is to help people improve and correct their code, not to help people cheat on (school) assignments

Comment: Transforming text / ideas to code is a skill you need to develop anyway as _you_ are the programmer. So try to write your own code, share it here, and we'll try to help where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `StringBuilder` and `Map` to solve your problem:

```
String str = "my1kiran4name2is3";

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        key.append(c);
    } else {
        if (key.length() > 0) {
            map.put(Integer.valueOf(key.toString()), value.toString());
            key.setLength(0);
            value.setLength(0);
        }
        value.append(c);
    }
}
map.put(Integer.valueOf(key.toString()), value.toString());

String response = String.join(" ", map.values()); // my name is kiran
```

The idea here is to loop over all the characters and check if digit or not, then in the end store the number as a key in the map and the string as a value.

Answer (score 1):

As a heads-up that as a reviewer, I **wouldn't approve** the next code because it's hard to read and maintain.
But in case there is someone like me and likes regexes and streams:

```
    String string = "my1kiran4name2is3";
    Map<Integer, String> map =
            Arrays.asList(string
                    .split("(?<=\\d)"))
                    .stream()
                    .map(s -> s.split("(?=\\d)"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap((e -> Integer.parseInt(e[1])), e -> e[0]));
    string = map
            .values()
            .stream()
            .collect((Collectors.joining(" ")));
    System.out.println(string);
```

A little explanation:

1. (?<=\d) is positive lookbehind. We split the String if the value before the match is a digit. So as a result we have (my1, kiran4, name2, is3)
2. (?=\d) is positive lookahead we map the String if the Value ahead is a number. So as a result we have (my 1, kiran 4, name 2, is 3)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, just for fun:

```
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile("([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)");
    String input = "my1kiran4name2is3";
    Map<Integer,String> words = new TreeMap<>();
    Matcher matcher = re.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        words.put(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2)), matcher.group(1));
    }
    String output = String.join(" ", words.values());
    System.out.println(output);
```